# SSRS Date Time Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]I have an SSRS report that I would like to set the default end date to be 6 months prior to today's date and the start date to be 2 years prior to the end date. If I run it in September, End date would be March, next month End date should automatically update to April.   How can I configure this in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Create the parameters, and set the Default values as below:

Start Date:`=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -30, Today()))`

End Date:`=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -6, Today()))`

Use these parameter values in the data set queries to filter out the results.

Comment: tried that and this is the error I recieved: The value provided for the report parameter 'StartDate' is not valid for its type.

Comment: I also tried changing "Now" to GETDATE(). Same Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start Date:`=DateAdd(m, -30, GetDate())`

End Date:`=DateAdd(m, -6, GetDate())`

Here are great references:

[SQL Server DATEADD() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)

[SQL Date Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The below expression will work as per your need, you need to put these in the parameters default value section and opt for "specify values" -

**StartDate**  `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-30,Now())`

**EndDate**    `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-6,NOW())`

Also choose the parameters as `Date/Time`.
Below Snapshot to show the difference I chose Start Date as `Date/Time` and End Date as `Text`
[image]

Comment: My data type is DateTime is that why I am receiving the "value provided for the report parameter 'StartDate' is not valid for its type" error?

Comment: I am suspecting you need to `FORMAT` your `datetime`. Do check your system date format, as SSRS is expecting all date parameters to be in US format.

Comment: They are all in US format, not sure why it keep throwing me the "The value provided for the report pararment is not a valid type" error.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshot for reference, if possible display the StartDate/EndDate values in some textbox on the report and check.To validate the value you can always use `IsDate` and then decide what needs to be shown.

Comment: StartDate DATETIME
  , EndDate DATETIME
  ,
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT  AD.AccountNumber
              , DealerNameNumber
              , DealerNumber
              , DatePurchased as DatePurchased

Comment: @user2671286 - what I need to understand from the code that you have put?